# trying to add an if else statement to ask user wether or not a compression must be added

Tags: bash, compression

this bash script is backing up a file or folder , i need to add an option to compress the files the user has selected.

this is my code , is my option for asking yes or no in the right place for the script, and what paramaters ?

```
#!/bin/bash
#

backup_file=`date +%F_%R`_my_backup.tar

clear

echo *******************************************
echo
echo "**********Today's date is $(date)********"
echo  "The current directory $(pwd)"
echo
echo "***files in this directory are***"
echo -e "A full list of contents follows: $(ls -R)\n"
echo
echo


echo   *******Custom  Backup Program*******

echo

echo   ":Option 1:  Create a backup"

echo   ":Option 2:  Exit backup program"

echo -n "Enter your choice 1, 2  : "

read choice

case $choice in

1) echo "perform a backup"
      echo "Enter full path for backup"
      read filepath
      echo " Enter destination"
      read location
      if [  -d $filepath ] || [ -f $filepath ]
        then
        echo "would you like to compress ? y/n   ***** this is where i think it should be followed by if and else ?


         tar -cvzf $location/$backup_file  $filepath
         echo "File $filepath$backup_file has been created."
         echo "Here are you backup files"

        else
          echo "the $filepath does not exist"
      fi


   2) echo "Backup cancelled " ;;
esac
```

Comment: I, personally, don't actually get what in fact your question is. If you wish the user to be prompted in order to get the y/n answer, your if goes to the place you indicated...

Comment: im asking what structure my if and else statment would be after the user chooses yes or no , no will be standard tar and yes would ad the z switch to compress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're very close. See amendments to your code

```
echo   *******Custom  Backup Program*******
echo
echo   ":Option 1:  Create a backup"
echo   ":Option 2:  Exit backup program"
echo -n "Enter your choice 1, 2  : "

read choice    
case $choice in  
   1) echo "perform a backup"
      echo "Enter full path for backup"
      read filepath
      echo " Enter destination"
      read location
      if [  -d $filepath ] || [ -f $filepath ]
        then
        echo "would you like to compress ? y/n" 
         #  ***** this is where i think it should be followed by if and else ?
         read compressed
         if [[ $compressed ~= [Yy]* ]] ; then
             tar -cvzf $location/$backup_file  $filepath
             echo "File $filepath$backup_file.gz has been created."
             echo "Here are you backup files"
         else 
             tar -cvf $location/$backup_file  $filepath
             echo "File $filepath$backup_file has been created."
             echo "Here are you backup files"
         fi   
        else
          echo "the $filepath does not exist"
      fi
   2) echo "Backup cancelled " ;;
esac
```

You can also achieve same with nested case statement, which would be my preference, i.e.

```
 . . . .
read choice
case $choice in

  1) echo "perform a backup"
      echo "Enter full path for backup"
      read filepath
      echo " Enter destination"
      read location
      if [  -d $filepath ] || [ -f $filepath ]
        then
        echo "would you like to compress ? y/n"
         #  ***** this is where i think it should be followed by if and else ?
         read compressed
         case $compressed in
           [Yy]* )
             tar -cvzf $location/$backup_file  $filepath
             echo "File $filepath$backup_file.gz has been created."
             echo "Here are you backup files"
           ;;
           * )
             tar -cvf $location/$backup_file  $filepath
             echo "File $filepath$backup_file has been created."
             echo "Here are you backup files"
           ;;
         esac  
        else
          echo "the $filepath does not exist"
      fi
   2) echo "Backup cancelled " ;;
esac
```

I'm not sure what your message means "Here are your backup files", but that doesn' affect your question or the functionality of your script.

Comment: thank you very much for your help !! worked like a treat ! just had too amend a few things and works perfectly !

Comment: Hi, Glad that helped. I have cleaned up my message so that there is a closing dbl-quote for `... compress y/n ?"` , and commented out the remainder of the line. Feel free to accept this answer by clicking on the green arrow that appears when you click on the up-arrow at the top left of my answer ;-). Good luck and keep posting.